# Error in Pandas using, miniconda, Jupyter notebook and python 3.7

Tags: pandas

When i run covid = pd.read_csv('data.csv') using Jupyter, pandas and python 3.7, i get the following error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4552\740331431.py in 
----> 1 covid = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a file named `pandas.py` that shadows the real module pandas/pd.

Look up in your current directory (and/or your project directory) for this file and **rename it** to something other than these :

```
['BooleanDtype', 'Categorical', 'CategoricalDtype', 'CategoricalIndex', 'DataFrame', 'DateOffset', 'DatetimeIndex', 'DatetimeTZDtype', 'ExcelFile', 'ExcelWriter', 'Flags', 'Float32Dtype', 'Float64Dtype', 'Float64Index', 'Grouper', 'HDFStore', 'Index', 'IndexSlice', 'Int16Dtype', 'Int32Dtype', 'Int64Dtype', 'Int64Index', 'Int8Dtype', 'Interval', 'IntervalDtype', 'IntervalIndex', 'MultiIndex', 'NA', 'NaT', 'NamedAgg', 'Period', 'PeriodDtype', 'PeriodIndex', 'RangeIndex', 'Series', 'SparseDtype', 'StringDtype', 'Timedelta', 'TimedeltaIndex', 'Timestamp', 'UInt16Dtype', 'UInt32Dtype', 'UInt64Dtype', 'UInt64Index', 'UInt8Dtype', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__deprecated_num_index_names', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__docformat__', '__file__', '__getattr__', '__git_version__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_config', '_is_numpy_dev', '_libs', '_testing', '_typing', '_version', 'api', 'array', 'arrays', 'bdate_range', 'compat', 'concat', 'core', 'crosstab', 'cut', 'date_range', 'describe_option', 'errors', 'eval', 'factorize', 'get_dummies', 'get_option', 'infer_freq', 'interval_range', 'io', 'isna', 'isnull', 'json_normalize', 'lreshape', 'melt', 'merge', 'merge_asof', 'merge_ordered', 'notna', 'notnull', 'offsets', 'option_context', 'options', 'pandas', 'period_range', 'pivot', 'pivot_table', 'plotting', 'qcut', 'read_clipboard', 'read_csv', 'read_excel', 'read_feather', 'read_fwf', 'read_gbq', 'read_hdf', 'read_html', 'read_json', 'read_orc', 'read_parquet', 'read_pickle', 'read_sas', 'read_spss', 'read_sql', 'read_sql_query', 'read_sql_table', 'read_stata', 'read_table', 'read_xml', 'reset_option', 'set_eng_float_format', 'set_option', 'show_versions', 'test', 'testing', 'timedelta_range', 'to_datetime', 'to_numeric', 'to_pickle', 'to_timedelta', 'tseries', 'unique', 'util', 'value_counts', 'wide_to_long']
```

Comment: I can't figure out the directory with a file pandas.py.  Still stack with this error.